# How to delete all sub array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

In my MongoDB database, I have a collection 'produits' with documents like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6048e97b4a5f000096007505"
    },
    "modeles": [
        {
            "id": "OppoA3",
            "pieces": [
                {
                "id": "OppoA3avn"      
                },
                {
                 "id": "OppoA3bat"      
                }]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id": "OppoA1",
            "pieces": [
                {
                "id": "OppoA1avn",
                },
                {
                "id": "OppoA1batt",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I delete all modeles.pieces from all my documents.

I managed to delete with a filter on modeles.id but with that code but not on all the collection

```
db.produits.update(
    {marque_id:'OPPO', 'modeles.id':'RENOZ'},
    {$set:
        {
            'modeles.$.pieces': []
        }
    }
    , { multi : true }
)
```

I would like all documents like this finally

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6048e97b4a5f000096007505"
    },
    "modeles": [
        {
            "id": "OppoA3",
            "pieces": []
        }, 
        {
            "id": "OppoA1",
            "pieces": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a javascript loop like this, but i think it's not best practice

```
 async removePieces(){
    var doc
    try {
      doc =  await produitModel.find()
      for (var produit of doc) {
        for (var modele of produit.modeles) {
          const filter = {'marque_id': produit.marque_id, 'modeles.id': modele.id}
          const set = {
                        $set: {
                          'modeles.$.pieces': []
                        }
                      }

          await db.collection('produits').updateOne(filter, set)
        }
      }
      console.log('removePieces() ==> Terminé')
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    db.produits.update({
      modeles: {//This is because your second document will create failure otherwise
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "modeles.$.pieces": []
      }
    },
    {
      multi: true
    })
```

Comment: I tried but it's impossible 
`Error : The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Comment: of course, you just need to reset it to empty array. Do test this logic, making sure it fits your need.

Comment: Error yet `"code" : 28,  "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'pieces' in element {modeles: [`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I update my edit question because my exemple document was badly formatted